# cmake + conan 2.0 + boost with default cmake_exe template not properly injecting dependencies in generated files

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, conan, conan-2

```
PS C:\Dev\test> conan --version
Conan version 2.0.9
PS C:\Dev\test> cmake --version
cmake version 3.27.1
```

I am trying to make a boost-cmake-conan 2.0 hello world using the default cmake_exe template.

1. In an empty folder `conan new cmake_exe -d name=myprojectname -d version=0.1`
2. add requirement `boost/[>=1.82.0]` to conanfile.py

   For reference the conanfile.py now looks like this

   ```py
   from conan import ConanFile
   from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMake, cmake_layout, CMakeDeps


   class myprojectnameRecipe(ConanFile):
       name = "myprojectname"
       version = "0.1"
       package_type = "application"

       # Optional metadata
       license = "<Put the package license here>"
       author = "<Put your name here> <And your email here>"
       url = "<Package recipe repository url here, for issues about the package>"
       description = "<Description of myprojectname package here>"
       topics = ("<Put some tag here>", "<here>", "<and here>")

       # Binary configuration
       settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

       # Sources are located in the same place as this recipe, copy them to the recipe
       exports_sources = "CMakeLists.txt", "src/*"

       def requirements(self):
           self.requires("boost/[>=1.82.0]")

       def layout(self):
           cmake_layout(self)

       def generate(self):
           deps = CMakeDeps(self)
           deps.generate()
           tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
           tc.generate()

       def build(self):
           cmake = CMake(self)
           cmake.configure()
           cmake.build()

       def package(self):
           cmake = CMake(self)
           cmake.install()
   ```

   and the cmakelist.txt

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
   project(myprojectname CXX)



   add_executable(myprojectname src/myprojectname.cpp src/main.cpp)



   install(TARGETS myprojectname DESTINATION "."
           RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
           ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
           LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
           )
   ```
3. Having previously setup my profile, running `conan install . --build missing` gives all the proper files under `/build/` and the following output

```
======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): Calling generate()
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): Generators folder: C:\Dev\test\build\generators
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json. Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-default' if using CMake>=3.23
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): If your CMake version is not compatible with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Dev\test\build\generators\conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW'
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): CMakeToolchain generated: ..\..\CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.py (myprojectname/0.1): Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully
```

4. And adding a simple hello world taken from Boost documentation

```cpp
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

   std::cout << "Type in any number: ";

   std::for_each(
       in(std::cin), in(), std::cout 
               << (boost::lambda::_1 * 10) 
               << "\nType in another number: " );
}
```

5. `conan build .` will finalize the install and call generate from our `conanfile.py`, but looking at the generated files no mention of boost either in libs or include directories is created in the Visual Studio project files. Of course this gives the following compiling error

```
C:\Dev\test\src\main.cpp(14,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/lambda/lambda.hpp': No such file or directory [C:\Dev\test\build\cli 
ent-server-algo-computing-grid.vcxproj]
```

This error would have been fixed in conan 1.0 by adding a reference to `conanbuildinfo.cmake` in our cmakelists.txt and calling `conan_basic_setup()` which is now deprecated and other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399769/how-to-create-conanbuildinfo-cmake-file-in-conan-2-without-install-folder-opti) suggest that we don't need to add it anymore.

Of course I could manually add the `find_package` as suggested in the conan 2.0 documentation, `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories` clauses, but I'd prefer if I could at least have generic `CONAN_LIBS` or `CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables like in conan 1.0 so I just have to update my conanfile.py if I add another lib. So what's going on and why can't CMakeDeps or CMakeToolchain properly inject boost?

Comment: Yes, the recommended way is to do ``find_package()`` and ``target_link_libraries()``. This is the very demanded "transparent integration" that means the resulting ``CMakeLists.txt`` is completely generic and Conan-agnostic. The ``CONAN_XXX`` variables looks convenient and easy on the surface, but are no longer good known CMake practices, and using CMake ``find_package()`` and CMake modern targets allows more idiomatic CMake and can also work better at scale. Plus not generating lock-in.

Comment: Quite frankly, I have never got Conan to play ball with boost. It just does not work. I switched to vcpkg which has a set of vetted packages that they make sure work with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to modify a user `CMakeLists.txt` with `CONAN_XXX` variables is not a recommended good practice anymore:

- CMake no longer recommends using variables to define dependencies information. The CMake recommended way is to use `find_package()` and targets via `target_link_libraries()`. As an example, imagine adding `test_requires("gtest/...")`. You certainly don't want your main app to be accidentally linked with `gtest` library. The `CONAN_LIBS` approach will likely do that, while with `target_link_library()` will perfectly define the right package and library dependencies for the right executables and libraries.
- The resulting `CMakeLists.txt` is completely standard and Conan-agnostic. This has several advantages as not generating any lock-in.

`CMakeDeps` went in this direction following massive feedback from the community towards this fully "transparent" integration in which the `CMakeLists.txt` does not end with any Conan references.

Comment: In the post I linked you commented "That means it is not necessary to modify the CMakeLists.txt at all to use Conan packages. " but now you're saying the standard way is to actually manually specify all the packages I downloaded with conan? 

Also, if that's the case, what would it cost to add a `self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_find_mode", "auto")` where I could just include `${BUILD_DIR}/conan_deps.cmake` or add a macro in cmakedeps_macros.cmake that I could refer to in my cmakelists.txt which would honestly make things much easier in simple cases and facilitate adoption of conan 2.0.

Comment: This is nothing related to Conan 2.0. The transparent integration of ``CMakeDeps`` + ``CMakeToolchain`` has been in Conan 1.X for years now, and recommended to switch to it from some time (https://docs.conan.io/1/conan_v2.html)

Comment: No, no need to specify "all" packages downloaded with Conan. Just the direct dependencies that you want to link with. There can be tenths of transitive dependencies, it is not needed to specify the ``find_package()`` for all of them. And the reasons are described above, like the global automatic approach generates **wrong linking** in too many situations. It looks like easier on the surface, but years of experience and the feedback of many thousands of users proved that it can be very problematic and not worth it, and it is what moved into the direction of ``CMakeDeps``

Comment: I wasn't referring to transitive dependencies but that answers the question nonetheless. It seems I was using Conan for the wrong reasons. I was looking for a package manager that could also drive the building pipeline with as less interventions from me as possible in simple cases. Of course as complexity grows, some bigger use cases could end up having special needs where an automatic approach would cause issues. But I've seen some developers have created ways for that automatic approach with the premake integration.